# Maximum sum of gcd

Tags: algorithm

There are two arrays with natural numbers. It is necessary to calculate the maximum sum of GCD, using permutations.

For example:

```
A = [1,3,5,7,9]
B = [15,20,30,40,50]
```

We can get the maximum sum of GCDs, for example, by the following mixing:

[image]

And the answer to this test will be 13. (3+3+5+1+1)

The length of the arrays is equal to `N`. And `N` can be from 1 to 200.

I tried to brute force all the combinations, but such a solution does not fit the timeline

Please tell me the algorithm for solving this problem.

The numbers from the array can be from 1 to 10^16.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my approach:

1. First let's create a  weighted bipartite graph, elements of array A will belong to left side, elements of array B - right side, and the weight of some edge `a->b` is `gcd(a,b)`
2. Now problem is reduced to optimal assignment problem which can be solved with various well known ways like Min-Cost-Max-Flow, Hungarian algorithm, etc.

Comment: I am not very good at graph theory. And I don’t fully understand what flow is. But you are talking about the minimum cost of maximum flow. It will be more logical to look for the maximum cost of the path in the graph

Comment: Well yes I called it "minimum cost maximum flow" cause that's how this problem is called in computer science so you would have easier googling, we can just multiply all weights by -1 to find maximum cost maximum flow

Comment: I wrote the code using the Hungarian algorithm, but it is not completely correct. Please tell me where I was wrong.

Comment: @yoloy maybe an overflow? `int gcd = __gcd(A[i],B[j]);` it seems you still have ints in places

Comment: Oh sorry. I did not see that the summation occurs in INT